# nopin='nopin' code not working on individual images

Tags: html, css, blogger, pinterest

Having installed my own Pinterest hover button to appear over the center of blog post images, I now have the issue that on certain pages/images I do not want that same hover button to appear (aren't I fussy!).

Common advice seems to be to add >> `nopin='nopin` << to the specific img src code on the page in question. I have also tried >> `data-pin-nopin="true"` << neither of which are working to remove/hide the pop-up pin-it button.

What the former *is* doing, however, is disabling the Pinterest for Chrome function.

Ideally I don't want any pin-it buttons to show up on these images, but disabling the center one only would be a workable solution.

TL;DR >> Yes to custom pin buttons on blog post images, No to pin buttons on any other images.

Suggestions?

Here one of the pages I want to hide the pop-up button from >> http://guplayground.blogspot.ca/p/library.html <<

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add `class='nopin'` to image code, eg:

```
<img class='nopin' src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4319/35968863432_8becca78cb_b.jpg" />
```

Thanks to http://www.bloggersentral.com/2012/11/pinterest-pin-it-button-on-image-hover.html for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

For me `data-pin-no-hover="true"` did the trick.